# Node content is not shown

Tags: 7, nodes, javascript

I installed DrupalGap. Everything works fine so far, except that the node body is not displayed. I have none of the mentioned interfering modules installed. I also tried with a fresh Drupal 7 installation in a new test environment with the same result.

I ask for advice or hints.

Note: values are handed over. I can display the body instead of the title. But after clicking a node title, in the sub sequent page only the titel and the comments are shown.

[image: Watchdog log]

Additional information: the edit mode of a node shows the html content. Only the view does not show the content (body)

10th of Jan 2020: I made a clean Drupal 7.69 installation with minimum modules (in order to exclude module interferences) with DrupalGap 7.x-1.17 on my localhost. Same effect - not showing the node body in View mode. I wonder what configuration the DrupalGap demo does have? There it works.

Comment: Clear Drupal's cache. I don't know about DrupalGap, but in vanilla Drupal "Main Page Content" block "contains" the fields for a node. It's usually in Admin-Structure-Blocks, "Content" region. It is `$variables['content']` during node processing, and `$content` in template files. Use Devel and `hook_preprocess_node` in custom module to see the body: `dpm($variables['content']['body'][0]['#markup']);` Enable `Theme debug mode`, look at the page source and the node template filename is under `CALL: theme('node')`  Look in it for `print render($content);` You can also add `dpm($content');` there

Comment: Also, check Drupal watchdog and the web server error logs to see if they have entries that explain what is happening.

Comment: Clearing cache did not make a change.

In watchdog protocols is written 'page not found' after I tried to open a node's content. The message seems to be incomplete.

Comment: Actually the error message is complete. My guess is it has to do with the [DrupalGap SDK](https://github.com/signalpoint/DrupalGap) and/or a [DrupalGap Module](https://drupalgap.org/project/modules). One or more aren't installed or are broken somehow. The error indicates DrupalGap is trying to build the path to a JavaScript file for one of its modules, but what it has for the module's sub-directory and JavaScript filename are empty: `path/to/drupalgap_sdk_dir/mobile-application/app/modules/[MODULE_DIRECTORY]/[JAVASCRIPT_FILE].js?[MODULE_PARAM]=157...` Try looking at the DrupalGap config page.

Comment: Also, the [docs for DrupalGap Modules](http://drupalgap.org/node/74) may be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response!
I went through the documentation multiple times. It does not say a lot about the config file.
Could  it be that in the settings file some js file is not included? 

I have two installations with the same problem. Is a fundamental problem in drupalgap core or in my infrastructure?

Comment: `Could it be that in the settings file some js file is not included?` Look in the settings file. When I went to install their SDK by pushing the button on their config form, it tried to download a zip file to Drupal root. It's strange that they would assume that directory would be writable, and even stranger that they don't show any message when the download fails. If the SDK files are there, you will see on the config page "The SDK is already installed." If it isn't, the textfield for the "Directory" will still be enabled, but they don't show a message saying the SDK files are missing.

Comment: It says "The SDK is already installed." 

Regardless I will try to install the SDK manually in a test Environment.

Comment: I made fresh installations of Drupal and DrupalGap on my localhost. Same result = node content ist not shown in View mode.
I really do not know any more what to check.
Can it have to do with newer PHP version? - DupalGap is 3 years old now...

Comment: Have you [set the DrupalGap display mode](http://docs.drupalgap.org/7/Entities/Display_Modes) for your content type(s)?

Comment: That is it! :-) Obviously I did not recognize this in the documentation for weeks! Sry for causing you time! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the Body field was not added to the [DrupalGap Display Mode](http://docs.drupalgap.org/7/Entities/Display_Modes) for the content type:

> By default, there are no fields displayed using the DrupalGap Display
>   Mode. We need to specifiy which fields, labels and formats will be
>   used when our nodes are displayed in the mobile app. Do this for each
>   content type.